# How to Change the color of each group in boxplot (highcharts)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, boxplot

I am using Highcharts boxplot = > for this i want to have different color for each group (each box).
I can provide color at series level, but that will change the color of all boxes.
What i want to Achieve is to have different colors for each box.
Looking for the the best way to achieve that.

Please have a look at

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'boxplot'
},

title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Box Plot Example'
},

legend: {
    enabled: false
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    title: {
        text: 'Experiment No.'
    }
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Observations'
    },
    plotLines: [{
        value: 932,
        color: 'red',
        width: 1,
        label: {
            text: 'Theoretical mean: 932',
            align: 'center',
            style: {
                color: 'gray'
            }
        }
    }]
},

series: [{
    name: 'Observations',
    data: [
        [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
        [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
        [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
        [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
        [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
    ],
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
    }
}, {
    name: 'Outlier',
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
        [0, 644],
        [4, 718],
        [4, 951],
        [4, 969]
    ],
    marker: {
        fillColor: 'white',
        lineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
    }
}]
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/box-plot/

thanks

Comment: i am able to do this, by creating a new series foe each box and then applying different color to each series, but to manage x-axis categories i will have to add some empty arrays.. which i don't like.

http://jsfiddle.net/ccvhrhpr/

Answer (score 1):

After some research i found the Answer,

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        colorByPoint: true
    }
}
```

thanks